# ubuntu 22.04 external monitor not detected with thinkpad E14

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

I recently updated ubuntu 22.04 and my external monitor(Samsung M7) is not detected properly.
I'm using thinkpad E14 Gen3 with Ryzen and Radeon, so I updated radeon graphic drivers for ubuntu 22.04 but it doesn't work for me.

The external monitor is connected with USB-C cable. Since the monitor represents the device connected with USB-C and my laptop also represents that it is charging, so it does not seem to be a problem with cable.

Is there any way to get my monitor detected?

xrandr shows below:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```